# DockerSDK: exec_run output to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I am writing a python3 script that uses Docker SDK to execute some functions in a container.
So my python script looks like this:

```
data = {a:"1", b:"2"} #values that I want to save
data_string = json.dumps(data) #string out of it
container_nodered=client.containers.get("my_container")
container_nodered.exec_run(["echo", data_string,">","/test.txt"])
```

The idea is simple. I have a JSON variable, I create a string out of it and then I want to save it in a file inside a docker container. To do that I want to echo it in the terminal and the output to be saved to a file. According to the [docs](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html) to that, I can use the operation `.exec_run()`. And since I have more than one operation I need to pass a list.

But it doesn't work.

Does someone know what my mistake is?

Comment: Can you set up an HTTP endpoint in your container, and use a library like `requests` to POST the JSON data to the application?  That would be safer than what you're showing here, and wouldn't require Docker-specific API calls.

Comment: The client wants a script that would work with container name/id. So, I am limited to using these functions